# Custom service with custom message

Tags: catkin, custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am trying to create a package in which I define my messages and use the same in defining services like

foo_msgs/msg/MS1.msg

foo_msgs/srv/SRV1/srv

where SRV1.srv contains a line with `foo_msgs/MS1[] some_name`

I have all the dependencies set in CMakeLists.txt file as

```
set( MESSAGE_DEPENDENCIES
std_msgs
geometry_msgs
)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED 
 COMPONENTS
 message_generation
 ${MESSAGE_DEPENDENCIES}
)

include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${catkin_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_message_files( DIRECTORY msg
FILES
AgentState.msg
AllAgentsState.msg
)

# the services
add_service_files( DIRECTORY srv
  FILES
  SetAgentState.srv
  GetAgentState.srv
  SetAllAgentsState.srv
  GetAllAgentsState.srv
 )

# generate the messages
generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ${MESSAGE_DEPENDENCIES})

#Declare package run-time dependencies
catkin_package( CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime ${MESSAGE_DEPENDENCIES})
```

But this always fails with this error

```
/opt/ros/hydro/share/genmsg/cmake/pkg-genmsg.cmake.em:50: error: <class 'genmsg.base.InvalidMsgSpec'>: Invalid declaration: pedsim_msgs/AgentState
```

I am using Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/102661/custom-service-with-custom-message/) by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1295 on 2013-11-19

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Within you package your service file needs to refer to its own messages without the package name:

```
AgentState state
```

instead of:

```
pedsim_msgs/AgentState state
```

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-11-21**:
While the top example is the normal usage, the other should work, too. I am nearly certain it did with rosbuild. Is this a catkin migration issue that needs to be documented?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-11-21**:
It is definitely not related to catkin since catkin is not involved in message generation at all. But genmsg was rewritten between Electric and Fuerte. May be in that process this was changed. If someone would like to verify that it was possible before it can be reimplemented again.